# BlackBerry based Push Notifications (Client Side)

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I want to develop a push notification receiving app for BlackBerry.

I have made few apps for iOS and Android platform. In both of these platforms client app has to register with APN/GCM to receive the notifications. In return APN/GCM returns a DeviceToken/RegistrationID that uniquely identifies the device.

I am not able to find whether the same process is applicable for BlackBerry also. If yes, how can we get a unique ID in this case.

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Push+Service

Comment: https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_services/push_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

fill up the form from the below url
https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121

you need to use corporate email account otherwise they will not reply you .